# Match filename with first letter in either lower or upper case in bash

Tags: bash

This is more of a general question, but I can't figure out how to google it since it's not regex matching.

Say I have a directory with

```
install_script
Install_script
[and to make it difficult]
xstall_script
```

If I want to remove just the install scripts, how do I do it?

I'm thinking something along the lines of

```
rm [iI]nstall_script
```

but that doesn't work.

Is there a class-specifier-like utility in bash?

Comment: "Doesn't work"? How doesn't it work? That's precisely the correct syntax for what you're saying you want to do.

Comment: What's wrong with `rm install_script Install_script`? Are you thinking of a more complex problem?

Comment: I just tried it again - I must have had a typo in the original attempt because it works now. I figured it wouldn't be the regex syntax but I guess it is. @CrisLuengo I am thinking of a more complex scenario, I wanted to know if it could be done first

Comment: @BrydonGibson, this is actually fnmatch syntax (also called "glob syntax"), not regex syntax -- they're not quite identical, but close enough on this point. Since the issue can't be reproduced, though, you might consider closing the question.

Comment: Agreed - I'll close it. Is fnmatch what bash uses? That would help me in future searches

Comment: bash actually implements its own extended version rather than using the C fnmatch standard library function, but the POSIX sh standard basically requires it to at least implement fnmatch's logic. See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs

Answer (score 1):

you can use

`rm -f {I,i}nstall_script`